# iOS - Access custom UITableViewCell property from another ViewController.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The main view of an iOS App, I'm currently working on is a `UITableViewController` (mainHp_TVC) containing several custom `UITableViewCells`.

I need to access one of these uiTableViewCells from a different UIViewController - as it basically has a count button that I need to hide, but i'm struggling and can't find any info to guide me.

How can I access this cell?  It is the first cell in the UITableViewController and only used in one instance and its class is HP_Header_TableViewCell

I have included both mainHp_TVC.h and HP_Header_TableViewCell.h and created an instance as follows -

```
HP_Header_TableViewCell *hpTC;
hpTC.msgsBtn.hidden = true;
```

But, I can't access the button property with the above - can anyone point me in the correct. direction?

Comment: You never actually assign anything to your `*hpTC` variable, so it references nothing. Make the assignment or provide more information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you sure that cell can be only in one instance, make property in view controller that holds table, and assign this cell when create it.

Latter in another controller you need link to mainHp_TVC instance to access cell;

**BUT in general is bad idea**, the right way is change data that fills table, and call reloadData in table to get refreshed UI.

Also please check comment from @danh

Comment: +1 but I want to emphasize... do it the 'right way' that @sage444 suggests.  VC2 must change the state of the model in some way that VC1 can detect when it's again visible.  VC1 can reload the table on viewWillAppear.